# SVM Cross-validation always same

Tags: r, svm

Using the following code, I am trying to perform leave-one-out cross-validation.

```
library(e1071)
library(plyr)

trainingdata<-read.table('data.txt', sep=",", header=TRUE)
f0 <- function(x) any(x!=1) & any(x!=0) & is.numeric(x)
trainingdata<-cbind(colwise(identity, f0)(trainingdata))

C <- 0
M <- 0
count <- nrow(trainingdata)
for(i in 1:count)
{
   actual <- trainingdata[i,]$label
   trainingtemp <- trainingdata[-c(i), ]

   model <- svm(factor(label)~., data=trainingtemp, method="C-classification",     
   kernel="sigmoid", C=0.1, gamma=0.01, cross=10)

   testdata <- trainingdata[i, ]
   prediction <- predict(model, testdata)
   prediction <- paste(prediction)

   if(actual==prediction)
      C <- C+1
   else
      M <- M+1
}

write.csv(data.frame(C,M))
```

The issue that I don't understand is that I always get the same value for C (correctly classified) and M (Incorrectly classified). The results are same in the following conditions:

1 - I have tried with different values for Cost and gamma (also tried best.svm() function)

2 - Tried different methods of classification + different kernels too.

3 - There are a total of around 50 features in the data set. Even, if any one feature is used  while building the model i.e. (svm(label~x1...) or svm(label~x2...), the result has no impact.

Is there any problem with the code? Data is quite large to be posted here.

Answer (score 1):

- Using the `iris` data and varying gamma for your svm call, I do get different predictions.
- I suggest that you put all predictions into a vector and compare predictions and correct labels after the cv is finished. That way you can check more easily whether predictions do actually change or not.
- We won't be able to help you any further without your data, and choices for C and gamma.
- (BTW, leave-one-out validation is *not* recommended, as you cannot iterate it. You may want to browse e.g. through [what is said about validation schemes on crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation))

Answer (score 0):

You are creating "trainingtemp" as your leave-one-out data but always passing the model the full data "trainingdata". Try modifying your model such:

```
model <- svm(factor(label)~., data=trainingtemp, method="C-classification",     
   kernel="sigmoid", C=0.1, gamma=0.01, cross=10)
```

Comment: Sorry. In fact, that is a mistake. I am actually passing trainingtemp. That was the last change that I tried so its mistakenly there.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know that much of R or exactly what your different calls are doing. I know that you're trying to do leave-one-out (LOO). Here are some things to check:

- Are you normalizing your data?, making all values lie between 0 and 1 (or between -1 and 1), either linearly or using the mean and the standard deviation? It is extremely important for SVMs and even more so for RBF kernels, you can get into numerical difficulties easily if you don't do this.
- Are you systematically parameter searching for a good value of C (or C and gamma in the case of an RBF kernel)? Doing cross validation or on a hold out set? It does not seem like you're doing that from my understanding of your R code. Why don't you try two fors outside of your code one testing 2^[-10...0] for gamma and 2^[-5...5] for C? This is what is really called cross validation, I think you're just doing the inner iteration and missing a couple of for loops.

Comment: Yes. The data is normalized between 0 and 1. best.svm searches for the best C and gamma. So I believe that there is not mistake but I have also manually chosen several values of Cost and gamma but the final results of C and M are always same. I just noticed one more thing that the prediction always results in only one class. The other class is never predicted for any one the examples during  LOO cross-validation process. How exactly one can move ahead with this situation in hand?

Answer (score 0):

This can be specific to your data as for different data I also get different values (as cbeleites pointed out).

So if you can put data in some sharable place.

Also as a minor comment I don't get the reason for using "cross=10" when you build a model.